# Ubuntu randomly freezes during boot

Tags: dual-boot, software-center, freeze, dependencies

I recently partitioned my hard drive to create an empty 43 GB drive on my Windows 7 64-bit Compaq Presario.

After the partition was complete, I used the Windows Installer from the Ubuntu website (wubi) to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit.

With my Dual Boot configuration complete, I restarted my computer and chose the partition with Ubuntu installed on it.

The first time it seemed okay until the login screen, where it froze on the login screen with a dotted purple background and a continuous animated drum sound playing.

I rebooted it and the same thing kept happening.

On around the fourth time, Ubuntu booted correctly.

Then, I messed around with it for a bit when I decided I should install Adobe Flashplayer from the Software Centre. It gave me an “unmet dependencies” error.

So I have two problems :

- Ubuntu only boots about one out of every four times correctly
- I cant download certain software from the software center, as i get an error message saying the dependecies are not met.

Comment: if you partitioned ur disk then why go with wubi? you can install it as a seperate os alongside of win7. it'll b less buggy

Comment: Would I just go to ubuntu.com, dowload 12.04 lts, and simply place the file i downloaded into my partition? Would it boot that way?

Comment: nope you need 2 delete the partition in windows then make a live usb or cd then reboot the pc with that live usb/cd and then select install ubuntu alongside windows thats it ubuntu will take care of everything else

Comment: Will this also work for 13.10?

Comment: Do I make a live USB drive with unetbootin?

Comment: yep it can be used and the method works for  too

Comment: in order to delete the partition in win7 u need to  go to disk management present in computer management(press start> right click on "computer" select manage) and in bios (or during startup) select usb as 1st preference for boot up to begin the installation

Comment: At the boot prompt, choose “memory test”. Let it run for at least one full pass.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us what kind of graphics are you using?
If you are using widely used nvidia, then the driver needs to be updated.Give the following command in the terminal

```
$sudo apt-get <drivername>-current
```

Here driver name will be nvidia.
Now you need to configure the driver from `additional driver` in `dash home` by activating them.
And for the second problem.Give the command

```
$sudo apt-get -f install
```

And then give

```
$sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you for this possible solution, I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: And im using nvidia

Comment: of course,don't give the '$' sign in the terminal...it's already there :D

Comment: I'm re-downloading Ubuntu 12.04 now, I will try those commands and report back with any errors